# Update the RecyclerView adapter items in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I put a Recycler View into my fragment activity , which contains a number of Card View items 
But when I click on the Refresh button, those items are created just for the first time

And when the Fragment is loaded for the next time, the items are not fetch again, and this is done only for the first time.

```
public class posts_fragment extends Fragment {
    private List<PostData> PostDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    PostDataAdapter adapter=new PostDataAdapter(PostDataList);
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_menu,container,false);
        recyclerView =view.findViewById(R.id.PostRecycleView);
        filldate();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return view;
    }

public void filldate() {

    //Start Get And Set Json Into Card View

    final String KeyUrl="http://www.rasamdev.ir/salehin/GetPost.php";
    final String KeyUsername="Key";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, KeyUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Start Pars
            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray("Posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String puid = object.getString("puid");
                        String Ptitr = object.getString("Ptitr");
                        String ptext = object.getString("ptext");
                        String pdate = object.getString("pdate");
                        String plike = object.getString("plike");
                        String pview = object.getString("pview");
                        String pimg = object.getString("pimg");
                        PostDataList.add(new PostData(pdate,ptext,puid,Ptitr,pimg,pview,plike));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            //End Pars


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(KeyUsername,"13581358r@R");
            return hashMap;
        }

    };


    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    //End
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Adapter Class :

```
public class PostDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostDataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<PostData> PostDataList ;
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView vPostContent, vPostDate, vPostAuthor, vPostTitr,VPostLikes,VPostViews;
        public ImageView vPostPhoto;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            vPostContent = v.findViewById(R.id.PostContentTv);
            vPostDate = v.findViewById(R.id.PostDateTv);
            vPostAuthor = v.findViewById(R.id.PostAuthorTv);
            vPostTitr = v.findViewById(R.id.PostTitrTv);
            vPostPhoto = v.findViewById(R.id.PostPhoto);
            VPostLikes=v.findViewById(R.id.PostLikeTv);
            VPostViews=v.findViewById(R.id.PostViewTv);

        }

    }

    public PostDataAdapter(List<PostData> postDataList) {
        PostDataList = postDataList;
    }

    @Override
    public PostDataAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_posts, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.vPostDate.setText(PostDataList.get(position).getPostDate());
        holder.vPostTitr.setText(PostDataList.get(position).getPostTitr());
        holder.vPostContent.setText(PostDataList.get(position).getPostContent());
        holder.vPostAuthor.setText(PostDataList.get(position).getPostAuthor());
        holder.VPostViews.setText(PostDataList.get(position).getPostViews());
        holder.VPostLikes.setText(PostDataList.get(position).getPostLikes());
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.vPostPhoto).execute(PostDataList.get(position).getImgpost());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return PostDataList.size();
    }
}
```

Data Class :

```
public class PostData {
    private String PostDate, PostContent, PostAuthor, PostTitr, imgpost, PostViews, PostLikes;

    public PostData(String postDate, String postContent, String postAuthor, String postTitr, String imgpost, String postViews, String postLikes) {
        PostDate = postDate;
        PostContent = postContent;
        PostAuthor = postAuthor;
        PostTitr = postTitr;
        this.imgpost = imgpost;
        PostViews = postViews;
        PostLikes = postLikes;
    }

    public String getPostDate() {
        return PostDate;
    }

    public void setPostDate(String postDate) {
        PostDate = postDate;
    }

    public String getPostContent() {
        return PostContent;
    }

    public void setPostContent(String postContent) {
        PostContent = postContent;
    }

    public String getPostAuthor() {
        return PostAuthor;
    }

    public void setPostAuthor(String postAuthor) {
        PostAuthor = postAuthor;
    }

    public String getPostTitr() {
        return PostTitr;
    }

    public void setPostTitr(String postTitr) {
        PostTitr = postTitr;
    }

    public String getImgpost() {
        return imgpost;
    }

    public void setImgpost(String imgpost) {
        this.imgpost = imgpost;
    }

    public String getPostViews() {
        return PostViews;
    }

    public void setPostViews(String postViews) {
        PostViews = postViews;
    }

    public String getPostLikes() {
        return PostLikes;
    }

    public void setPostLikes(String postLikes) {
        PostLikes = postLikes;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the adapter class? How it populates the data in there ??

Comment: ops ! sorry Topic Updated Please check Again

Comment: use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `PostDataList.add(new PostData(pdate,ptext,puid,Ptitr,pimg,pview,plike));` and see what happens

Comment: Thanks, my problem has been resolved